# npm install sqlite3 - gyp error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp, gyp, node-pre-gyp

I am working on clean Windows 10 installation.
When trying to run `npm install sqlite3` from `myproject` path, getting the following error:

```
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1474:34)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:917:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:687:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\dev\\source\\myproject\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v72-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\dev\\source\\myproject\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v72-win32-x64" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72" "--python=C:\\Python27" "--msvs_version=2017"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\dev\source\myproject\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\dev\source\myproject\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v72-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\dev\source\myproject\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v72-win32-x64 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72 --python=C:\Python27 --msvs_version=2017' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\dev\source\myproject\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\dev\\source\\myproject\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\dev\source\myproject\node_modules\sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.2
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

I've already tried some solution like `strict-ssl=false` but didn't find the solution that will work for me and still don't understand what is the root cause of this error.

I also tried to install some previous version on sqlite3 and got:

```
node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.1/node-v72-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http unable to get local issuer certificate (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
```

So I tried to make a direct GET request to this by changing the version from `v3.1.1` to `v4.1.1` and found out the following:

When making request with `SSL certificate verification` is `on`, the request fails, and when is `off` it success and downloads the file.

My conclusion is, there is an issue with certificate check on this package, and postman knows to handle it, the question is how to handle it on npm, specifically when running on windows.

Comment: Maybe `npm install -g node-gyp` and then `node-gyp configure` ?

Check: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

Comment: The link that you provided is the guide that I used as "official documentation".
So, I followed the steps there.
I can't run directly `node-gyp configure` because it is running by `npm`.